# Проблема с языком при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

При парсинге страницы данные упорно выдает на китайском языке, хотя в html шаблоне стоит en

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
url = "https://www.joytoy.com/warhammer/6719.html"
page = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

items = soup.find("div", class_="product_right clearfix")
print(items.text.strip())
```

Ответ:

```
极限战士入侵者
spot-goods
¥599

比例: 1:18
兵人高:120mm
材质: ABS PVC
产品重量: 0.25kg
包装尺寸: 254*208*176
发布时间: 9,2021
适用年龄: 17+
UPC:6973130371286
```

[image: Скрин шаблона html]

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код, который вернёт вам то что Вам нужно:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.joytoy.com/warhammer/6719.html'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}

def get_result(url, headers):

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.binary_location = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=".../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)  # Можно ждать до загрузки страницы, но проще подождать 10 секунд, их хватит с запасом
    html = driver.page_source
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    items = soup.find("div", class_="product_right clearfix")
    print(items.text.strip())


def main():
    get_result(url=url, headers=headers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вывод:

```
ULTRAMARINES INCURSORS
In-stock
$119.99

Product Scale: 1:18
Soldier Size:120mm
Material: ABS PVC
Weight： 0.25kg
Packing size(mm)： 254*208*176
Release: 9,2021
Applicable Age: 17+
UPC:6973130371286
```